# Detect this same string in dynamic generate inputs using vee validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Hi I have form with dynamic generated inputs by button "Add new input":

```
<li v-for="(input, i) in inputs" :key="i">
    <validation-provider
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        :name="`link_${i}`"
        :rules="`required|url|uniqueUrl:@link_${i}`"
    >
        <input
        v-model="inputs[i]"
        type="text"
        :name="`link_${i}`"
        class="form__input__text"
        />
        <div class="form__error">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
    </validation-provider>
</li>
```

I must add validation to check that the user has not entered the same url in other input.
I create validate:

```
extend('uniqueUrl', {
  params: ['target'],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    console.log('x', value !== target);

    return value !== target;
  },
  message: 'This address is added in a different input',
});
```

I have a problem, bacuse consol log `value !== target` return only `true`. It doesn't matter if I give the same url or different addresses.

I'm using vee-validate in version: `3.2.5`

Comment: What version of vee-validate are you using? Also note that with your current setup, the `uniqueUrl` field always references the value in the `loop`, which will always be the current value.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm using vee-validate in version: 3.2.5